# Mode of a dataframe with priority

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas so please bear with me. I want to apply mode on a dataframe but with a tweak. there can be four values [High,Medium,Low,NA] for Columns Item_1, Item_2 and Item_3. High with highest priority and Low being lowest. NA should be ignored.
Data is as shown below.

```
    date       Type  Item_1   Item_2  Item_3 Price
0   2021-01-01  A    High     Low     Low     20   
1   2021-01-01  A    High     Low     Low     20    
2   2021-01-01  A    Low      High    Low     20   
3   2021-01-01  A    Medium   High    High    20    
4   2021-01-01  B    Low      High    Low     15   
5   2021-01-01  B    Medium   High    High    15
6   2021-01-01  B    Low      Low     Medium  15
6   2021-01-02  A    NA       High    NA      30    
7   2021-01-02  A    NA       High    NA      30    
8   2021-01-02  A    NA       NA      NA      30
9   2021-01-02  A    NA       NA      Low     30
10  2021-01-02  A    NA       NA      Low     30
11  2021-01-02  A    NA       Low     High    30
```

Expected Output:

```
    date       Type  Item_1   Item_2  Item_3  Price
0   2021-01-01  A    High     High    Low     20  
1   2021-01-01  B    Low      High    High    15
2   2021-01-02  A    NA       High    Low     30
```

My use case is, As you can see for 1st row in **Item_1** now has value **High** as its most frequent.
But in **Item_2** Both ***Low*** and ***High*** have **same frequency** but High have more priority thus value is High in output.
In Item_3 Low is most frequent thus value Low.

**Edit:**
NA should be ignored. and second most availbe value should be as output as in case of date 2021-01-02 NA has highest frequency but second most frequent value is High.

The value NA does not correspond to NaN rather its a string object. similar to other categorical values. It's just that whenever there is even single High/Low/Medium for a date irrespective of the frequency of NA, I want to choose the categorical value which has second highest occurance/frequency

Comment: Is in DataFrame multiple rows with different datetimes ? If yes, you can add few rows to DataFrame in question for better understandinf what need ?

Comment: @jezrael Sorry for inconvinience, I've updated the data as you requested.

Comment: No problem , answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is multiple rows with different dates, so first reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then convert values to `ordered categorical`s and last get first mode per groups in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) in lambda function and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
cols = df.columns
df = df.melt(['date','Type','Price'])
df["value"] = pd.Categorical(df["value"], 
                             categories=["High", "Medium", "Low"], 
                             ordered=True)
df = (df.groupby(['date','Type','Price','variable'])['value']
        .agg(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(cols, axis=1))
print (df)
         date Type  Item_1 Item_2 Item_3  Price
0  2021-01-01    A    High   High    Low     20
1  2021-01-01    B     Low   High   High     15
2  2021-01-02    A  Medium    Low   High     30
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. Is there any way to retain the sequence of columns?

Comment: I want to groupby only date and still want to retain the Type and price column is there any way to do it?

Comment: @Rushi - Hmm, what is logic? Because if aggregate - use sme formula per `dates` how is possible remain another columns?

Comment: Thanks I worked it around. There is slight update in data if you could please help me out. There is extra value in data as NA which should be ignored and highest availbe value should be taken.

Comment: @Rushi Can you try change `lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]` to `lambda x: x.dropna().mode().iat[0]`?

Comment: The value NA does not correspond to NaN rather its a string object. similar to other categorical values. It's just that whenever there is even single High/Low/Medium for a date irrespective of the frequency of NA, I want to choose the categorical value which has second highest occurance/frequency.

Comment: I have updated the data for better understanding only if all values are "NA"  the ouput value will be NA else the categorical value with next second highest occurances.

Comment: @Rushi So you need `lambda x: 'NA' if x[x!= 'NA'].empty else x[x!= 'NA'].mode().iat[0]`?

Comment: Yes thank you. Just a doubt what if i want to add another value which should be ignored like NA. For example 'other' which also should be ignored.

Comment: @Rushi Use `lambda x: x.iat[0] if x[~x.isin('NA', 'other' )].empty else x[~x.isin('NA', 'other' )].mode().iat[0]`, but maybe more complicated if need some logic for NA or other. Tis solution return first value by iat[0]

Answer (score 1):

You could turn your Item columns into categorical and provide the ranking (your priority). For example for `Item_2`:

```
df["Item_2"] = pd.Categorical(df["Item_2"], ["High", "Medium", "Low"])
```

When you use mode it returns multiple values if more than 1 value has the highest frequency. But it will also order the results. By default in alphab etical order but because you turned your column into categorical it will use the ranking instead.

```
df["Item_2"].mode()
```

Will return

```
0    High
1     Low
Name: Item_2, dtype: category
```

Using `[0]` index you can always extract the top value.

```
df["Item_2"].mode()[0]
```

If you apply that to all columns you should get what you are looking for.